# Accessing the the values count in a hash Rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have grouped the elements by some attribute and assigned that to an instance variable and I need to get the over all records count at Rspec, here is my controller action looks like `@records =User.group_by(&:country)`

I need to test the count of records assigned on each key, how can I get that

Comment: `User.group(:country).count` will return a Hash structured with `country` as the key and the value for that key = actual count (integer).

Comment: Yes. How can I check the value at Rspec, like assigns[:records].count

Comment: If you do `count_by_country = User.group(:country).count` then you can do `count_by_country['name of the country'].to_i` (I added `.to_i` here in case `nil` is returned so it converts it to zero)